# How can i associate one or more field with each customer group in system.xml in magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, system.xml

I have a system.xml file in which i already have retrieved customer groups in a multiselectist field .Now i want to associate one field-To set some value for each customer group.How can i get these values from system.xml when customer clicks "proceed to checkout".And How can i redirect customer to */checkout/cart/ " .

[image: As shown in image where furthur checkout process is disabled]

Answer (score 0):

When you save in Configuration, the value of your custom field will save in table "core_config_data" with column path is **section_id/group_id/field_id** and the column value is what you choose/enter value in your custom field.

To get value of **section_id/group_id/field_id**, you can use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig`
in your constructor argument and set the class property `$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;`

Now to get the configuration value in your function, just use:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('section_id/group_id/field_id', 
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

It's look like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $valueCustomField = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('section_id/group_id/field_id', 
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

    //do something here
}
```

Comment: How can i assign each customer group a value from another field in system.xml?

Comment: I think you can use dynamic row. You can read this https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/admin/create-dynamic-row-configuration/

Comment: Please answer this "How can i get these values from system.xml when customer clicks "proceed to checkout".And How can i redirect customer to */checkout/cart/ "